# Django - M2M relations on save model

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

I have a Django Model that I use as Job for exporting the entire list of Users to a csv file.
Now I'm trying to do some modifications to this Job to make it possible to export a list of Users filtered by a few criteria such as Gender, DOB, Country, etc.

This is my model for the ExportUsersJob:

```py
class ExportUsersJob(models.Model):
    countries = models.ManyToManyField(Country, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Filter by Country'))

    def save(self, *args, from_job=False, **kwargs):
        super(ExportUsersJob, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        countries = [c.pk for c in self.countries.all()]

        # This will query the DB and print the results in a csv file
        export_users.delay(self.pk, countries)
```

The issue I'm having is that it seems that, at this point, django hasn't yet created the M2M relations, hence I never have countries here.
Based on suggestions from other answers, I've trying playing with the ModelAdmin by overriding the `save_model()` and `save_related()` methods and adding the M2M relations on the form instance, but it seems that `save_model()` runs before there's even an instance (so it doesn't let me add relations) and `save_related()` runs after  `save()` so it's too late.

Can somebody tell me how can I access the M2M relations in the `save()` method?
(btw, i'm using django 2.2.7)

Comment: It's however not entirely clear to me why you need a model: this looks more like a way to create an asynchronous task, so then a simple form can be used to obtain the data and export the right data as csv file.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem this is a bit legacy, but I guess the purpose was to keep the csv files. Using a model, every time you run the job you create a record that persists there with a link to download the csv file.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, thanks! The solution seems now obvious. In ```save_related()``` I have everything I need, so I can call the async task to create the csv file from there.